# Material UI Autocomplete select default option when page loads first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How to select a value by default in Material UI Autocomplete?

defaultValue does not work.

In this example, I would like to show the option as default and show it as selected.

```
  {
    id: "flying",
    name: "Flying"
  },
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/vj4fj?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this line in the Autocomplete selector:

```
defaultValue={data.find(ob => ob.id === "flying")}
```

like

```
<Autocomplete
        defaultValue={data.find(ob => ob.id === "flying")}
        id="my-autocomplete"
        options={data.sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name)}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
        // style={{ width: "20vw" }}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Hogwarts classes"
            variant="outlined"
            style={{ width: 300 }}
          />
        )}
        renderOption={handleRenderOption} // highlighter
      />
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but the box still shows Hogwarts classes which is the label. If I remove the label, it is blank.

Comment: Here is the working solution . Please check https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-autocomplete-highlight-my6o1?file=/src/App.js:301-805

Comment: I accepted the answer but then saw that we cant use value = because that makes its value permanently that initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by answer above, the correct answer is

```
defaultValue={data.find(ob => ob.id === "flying")}
```